# How to copy a file from one HDFS folder to another HDFS folder using Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop

Using the HDFS java API I can rename (move) a file in HDFS.  Is there a way to copy the file?  I'm not interested in distcp, I'm going to copy a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html) page, you can use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil` API

```
public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS,
           Path src,
           FileSystem dstFS,
           Path dst,
           boolean deleteSource,
           boolean overwrite,
           Configuration conf)
                    throws IOException
```

> Copy files between FileSystems.

You can get FileSystem with below API

```
final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

and pass it ti above api

Comment: Thanks, I'll also try to see if it copies in the same file-system

Comment: @hba Hello, did you test if it copies between same file-systems ?